# facebook graph api access token error

Tags: rest, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access facebook marketing api with access_token like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?key=value&amp;access_token=7675848474658758|u0498cm4u85a478c954858784
```

Getting error like this

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "rctvrtrtr"
   }
}
```

I googled and found that my token is expired. Possible !!

Second, I found this url from google with the description that every time it runs, will get new access token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This time I got error like this

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Malformed access token EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "txdtysyvyt"
   }
}
```

Is there any way I request fb graph api with passing app id and secret as access token to get data from facebook with new access token every time? If yes what should I do ?

Second How can I pass parameters in this url as well to get specific information ? Third, I've passed app id and secret. Does this means I dont need user id and password to access url ? Right ?

Please give your suggestions

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Did you solve this ?